# How can I upload multiple photos in one post on Google+ from G+ Android SDK?

Tags: android, upload, google-plus, photo

I want to know how to upload **multiple** photos at a time thru **google plus**?

I found how to upload one photo and one message at a time from google plus sample code.

```
String action = "/?view=true";
Uri callToActionUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url) + action);
String callToActionDeepLinkId = getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id) + action;

// Create an interactive post builder.
builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this, plusClient);

// Set call-to-action metadata.
builder.addCallToAction(LABEL_VIEW_ITEM, callToActionUrl, callToActionDeepLinkId);

// Set the target url (for desktop use).
builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url)));

// Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
builder.setContentDeepLinkId(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id),
        null, null, null);

// Set the message.
builder.setText("user message");

// Set the image
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("[user file path]"));
builder.setStream(uri);
```

Anyone knows about uploading multiple photos like facebook and twitter?

Comment: I have the same issue. Using two times .addStream make the activity crash

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `addStream()` method, unfortunately... it doesn't work. Indeed it makes the application crash.

After a long search, I finally got it: it's not possible if using the simplified G+ SDK! (the one dedicated to Android).

There is a second one, included in the Google API family that you can find there:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API

This one will let you build more advanced post, included, several pic one.

Unfortunately the second SDK is much more low level, not dedicated to Android, it's a kind of Java abstraction over http request.

Regards